# Using the present tense to write about future events as future events

Tags: tenses, subjunctive-mood

I'm an undergraduate student. Today, I was writing an email to my department's undergrad adviser to request a meeting to discuss what I will study next year. When I began to write the email, I wrote

> Dear Dr. X,
>
> Next year I complete the final year of my program.

When I read it aloud, it sounds right. However, I'm writing about an event in the future, and so I believe that I should have written

> Dear Dr. X,
>
> Next year I *will* complete the final year of my program.

However, the use of *will* seems to make the sentence more presumptuous.

I suspect that the first version is written subjunctively*. However, to the best of my knowledge, subjunctivesque constructions that resemble the first version are typically imperatives, and typically follow *that*. For example, 'It is required *that* she arrive before noon tomorrow.'

Is the first version grammatical. If so, why is it so; if not, why is not grammatical?

(Note: I asked this question in order to learn about English. I did not intend to ask for advice on what I should write in this email. Accordingly, I would prefer a answer that explicates the relevant grammatical, or linguistic, principles. Thank you.)

Comment: I feel "Next year I complete the final year of my program" is more presumptuous, leaving nothing to chance or change of plans. If you want the second variant to be less presumptuous, then how about "As per current progress (or schedule), I will complete the final year of my program next year" or "I am expecting to complete the final year of my program next year" ? [[ also refer : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/present-tense-for-future-events ]]

Comment: @Prem I agree. I think that "I plan to complete the final year of my program next year" would work best. Thank you for the advice. I should note that I intended to ask a more general question on grammar.

Comment: Since we really only have two tenses in English - past and "not past" - we commonly use the latter in many contexts other than "present". There's certainly nothing grammatically incorrect about saying *I go to work tomorrow* rather than drafting in auxiliary verbs *(I **will** go to work tomorrow)*. This is nothing to do with OP's "subjunctive/infinitive" examples.

Comment: If we have a "terminator" type of situation, then "I kill him last year, then I kill her last month" may not sound weird ungrammatical.

Comment: I expect to finish my program next year. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version is fine: see past questions (and their answers) regarding [Simple Present for Future Actions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55686/simple-present-for-future-actions) and [Present tense for future events](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/present-tense-for-future-events) for more information on the use of present tense in this way.

The notion that your second version is more presumptuous may arise somehow from the old *shall/will* usage distinction in the formation of the future. On that see [When should I use “shall” versus “will”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3/when-should-i-use-shall-versus-will) Briefly, according to the old-fashioned distinction outlined in the 2nd (Ernest Gowers) edition of H. W. Fowler’s *Dictionary of Modern English Usage,* forming the first-person future with *will* implies special certainty and/or iron determination, *shall* being the default modal for first-person futures. (This was only ever a thing in British English, I think.)

Finally, to complete the final year of the program is to complete the program, right? So there is a possible opportunity to trim four words without loss of meaning.