# Simple Present vs Simple Future

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

This is my first grammar-related post in this forum. It's my honour to be associated with professional native English teachers.

My question is based on the nuanced difference between Simple Present Tense vs Future Simple Tense. Look at the sentence below. To me, the word "will" is required here unless the writer replace "anymore" with "again" here. What do you think?

- I never go anywhere with Eric again.

Thank you,

English lover

Comment: Your wording is a little bit confusing. Which ones do you consider correct: *I never go anywhere with Eric again; I will never go anywhere with Eric again; I never go anywhere with Eric anymore* or *I will never go anywhere with Eric anymore*?

Comment: Related question, [Simple Present for Future Actions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55686/simple-present-for-future-actions) and [Present tense for future events](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/present-tense-for-future-events). Do you mean replace "again" with "anymore"?

Comment: Please do not be offended by the down-voting of your question, which has to do with what is appropriate to ask on EL&U and the requirement that you give examples (context) of how you will use any answer that is offered. Please review the help section for more information, and welcome to EL&U. With practice, you will find this to be a very hospitable community. Please read the link in the comment above.  Thank you!

Comment: I meant the sentence "I never go anywhere with Eric again." is wrong without "will". It should be, in my opinion, either "I will never go anywhere with Eric again." or "I never go anywhere with Eric anymore."

Comment: Please see my answer below, confirming your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. To make your example sentence grammatical and idiomatic, you would need to say either,

> "I will never go anywhere with Eric again."

or,

> "I never go anywhere with Eric anymore."

Comment: I previously have liked your comment. It was useful. Thank you.